# Advise host Sweden for EE build with MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager, hosting

I need advise choosing a good reliable hoster for a new EE build with MSM and a mix of 6 .SE and .ORG domains. Preferrably in Sweden because the organisations I work with want a local host. Thanks a lot for advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good answer for site owners in Sweden I am afraid, because we found none. We are now in the process to move to Nexcess (their server in the UK).